# Enable/Disable custom ribbon commands in MS Word

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

I have produced a ribbon in MS Word with custom macros associated with various buttons to automate a checking process. As part of this checking process, it needs to go to Person A before Person B can sign off on it.

To add rigor to this I want to disable the "Person B Sign Off" button in the ribbon until Person A's has been completed, this as well as disabling various other buttons with conditional triggers. I have looked into multiple avenues but nothing has even come close to working with articles I've found, I assume I need to edit the XML but what and how I'm not sure.

[image]

For example - Retrieve LLC would be greyed out until LLC has actually filled in comments

Any pointers or help would be really appreciated!

//////////////////Edit///////////////////////

To clarify, the buttons above have been added using macros written in VBA and using the Customize Ribbon tool to add in the tab, group and individual buttons.

My understanding now is I include the following XML code to call on a callback that includes the getEnabled function, I have that sorted I hope. The error I run into now is finding what the unique ID of the button's I have added are since they've not been created using XML, i.e. Retrieve LLC as highlighted above isn't going to be referenced as 'button id="Retrieve LLC"'

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="MyAddinIntialize">
    <ribbon startFromScratch= "false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Checking">
                <group id="GovernanceProgress">
                    <button id="RetrieveLLC" getEnabled="btnCheck1_getEnabled" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand you have to edit your XML - e.g.

```xml
 <button id ="btnLLCA" onAction="btnLLCA_onAction" 
                       getEnabled="btnLLCA_getEnabled"
                       getVisible="btnLLCA_getVisible"
                       />
```

`getEnabled` and `getVisible` are the keywords you were looking for.
The text after the equal sign is the name of the sub in your vba-code - like with onAction

And then create the according Subs in your VBA-Code:

```vb
'Callback for btnLLCA_getEnabled
Sub btnLLCA_getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = hasPersonAReviewed   -->adjust to your needs
End Sub

'Callback for btnLLCA_getVisible
Sub btnLLCA_getVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = hasProcessStarted  --> adjust to your needs
End Sub
```

So - what you have to do: return a `returnedVal` according to the status of your process.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response - how would I find the button id as I've figured that the name I give to these custom buttons are arbitrary since you can have 2 of the exact same name?

Comment: you can - within the callback-sub - access the ID via control.ID. There is also a tag-attribute which you could add to the xml and retreive via control.tag. Does this help?

Comment: Partially, certainly for in the sub it makes perfect sense. But when adding the XML in the first place, I have: <tab id="Checking" label="Checking">
    <group id="GovernanceProgress" label="Governance Progress">
     <button id="btnCheck1" label="Checker 1"
                        getVisible="btnCheck1_getVisible"                                                                But the 'btnCheck1' was just made up by me, it does not correspond to the actual button I, how do I find that id as it's not just the name that I give it as in the screenshot above 'Retrieve LLC' I assume

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you want to achieve ....

Comment: No worries, I appreciate this. I added an edit to the original question if that helps explain things better

Comment: I think you are on the wrong way: you don't create the buttons via VBA! Use e.g. https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.8.0 to create/edit the XML. Regarding the xml-snippet you provided: at least the label-tag is missing

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks that the add-in implements, the responses are cached.

For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getEnabled` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the status is returned, and then if the enabled status needs to be updated, the cached value is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method from VSTO add-ins. But for VBA macros you can use the `Invalidate` or `InvalidateControl` methods of the `IRibbonUI` interface. To get an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface you need to define the `onLoad` callback in the ribbon XML:

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

And you VBA macro could look like that:

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 
 
Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

You need to use the `getEnebled` callbacks in the ribbon XML markup to be able to invalidate the control's state - enabled or not. The signature of the `getEnabled` callback looks in the following way:

```
Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
```

You can find the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for this it has helped as I've progressed and got some stuff working. Unfortunately when I implement MyRibbon.Invalidate I get 'Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable not set' I have figured out that obviously the MyRibbon object is no longer defined but I am unable to retrigger the intialize function nor add a variable that stores the ribbon to reassign later. Do you have any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: I'd suggest posting this in a new thread because the answer has already been given.